# Refused to login into iOS app using Google auth

Tags: bug, login

1. Download the Stack Exchange app from the App Store.
2. Run it and login with Google.
3. Enter email and password for the Google account.
4. Successfuly login into Google.
5. Jump back to Stack Exchange app.
6. Get this error message:
   [image]

#### Notice I tried to:

- Reinstall the app.
- iPhone restart.
- Clear app data.

Comment: The app is dead. Use a browser and visit the site(s) instead. Will save lots of time and frustration. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I respectfully disagree, the iOS app is still very useful to me. (Of course, if you can't sign up, it'll be a lot harder to do useful things with it.)

Comment: @Glorfindel well... be really careful to never log out. :) (seriously though... not fixing bugs, even critical as this one, means one thing: the app is 100% dead)

Comment: The only thing they have to do is to fix the app token matched the back end authentication.